Adding a new object mid-animation
I don't seem to be able to find a way to add new objects mid-animation. I need my animation to show a gradually growing building, with bricks being added to it one by one. For some reason this simple idea seems to be impossible to realize in Blender. Can anyone help?

In the Properties editor, under the Object Properties, expanding the Visibility panel, there is a Show In Renders property that can be animated (RMB > "Insert Keyframe")

Sorry, you need to be much more specific about how or what you want to do get this answered. And I doubt this can be reduced to a simple "to get this, do that" answer. Certainly it is not impossible, depending on how you want to do that. When you say adding bricks, you mean simple boxes or more complex meshes with real looking structures? How should the building? Have you prebuilt parts that should appear or should all be generated on the fly?

Thanks to both StefLAncien and Gordon. I have already made a rather crude looking animation using vPython, it can be downloaded using this link: https://nb.anaconda.cloud/jupyterhub/user/08ec281d-b670-46b0-9928-ebd75223b70e/files/Shwed_animation/Shwed.py?_xsrf=2%7Cab0d21dc%7C06184f15d43f1910046d54ff4895bc6e%7C1714820692
A simple photo midway through building it brick by brick can be seen here: https://photos.app.goo.gl/hTZJKMTq6D8T7Tm3A

I have hoped I might be able to make a better-looking animation using Blender. I am going to try the "Visibility/Show In Renders" suggestion. In the meantime, I have come up with another approach. I created one template invisible brick, placed outside of the intended scene, and I always make duplicate of it, bring it to above the intended position, insert keyframe, having duplicated the material, animate change of alpha chanel from 0 to 1, insert keyframe, and then animat the downward movement to the intended position. As you can see, it is, indeed, extremely unwieldy.

Sorry, the link to anaconda.cloud does not work. This one should work: https://github.com/LovelyCobra/Shwedagon_Animation/blob/main/Shwed.py

Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

The Mask modifier is restricted to masking vertices by vertex-weight. But Geometry Nodes permits appearing / disappearing objects in a collection, instances, or, as here, Mesh Islands:

In this example, all the bricks belong to one object, but they are separate Mesh Islands, so can be discriminated per island.
In this example, their appearance is controlled by an animated texture, but could equally be controlled by any other animated attribute. That could be vertex-weights from Dynamic Paint with animated brushes, or an Image Sequence, or Mesh Boolean .. all depending on your preferred workflow, so I would be happy to extend this answer to suggest something that suits.


Wow, this is exactly what I have been looking for. However, I really am a Blender beginner, still. Are there any video tutorials regarding this that I could follow to learn all the above?

Well,  this particular method is invented on the spot, so, no.. but its components are not too bad: 1: Procedural gradients.. maybe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIjCqR3g_Es . That toot is about shaders, but you would do the same sort of thing inside Geometry Nodes, to make an animated mask. The remainder of the effect is separating the geometry in Geometry Nodes, according to whether the mask passes a threshold. That's just the one green node in the GN tree. The only subtlety is making the effect per-brick, if all the bricks are in one object.

That's done by adding up the values of the mask  for all the vertices in each  mesh island, and testing whether the total passes a threshold (0, for simplicity). That means only one vertex of the brick has to pass 0, and the whole brick will appear.
